# Converting the C++/CX "delegate" object over to its equivalent in C++/WinRT

Tags: c++-cx, c++-winrt

I'm new to WinRT. I'm converting my Windows UWP app written C++/CX over to C++/WinRT. I have a C++/CX `ref` class that basically does the same thing as the `Microsoft.VisualStudio.PlatformUI.DelegateCommand` class does in C#. My C++ class implements `ICommand` where the `Execute` and `CanExecute` callbacks are handled by delegates. The abbreviated code for the header file looks like this:

```
public delegate void ExecuteDelegate(Platform::Object^ parameter);
public delegate bool CanExecuteDelegate(Platform::Object^ parameter);

public ref class DelegateCommand sealed :
    Windows::UI::Xaml::DependencyObject,
    Windows::UI::Xaml::Data::INotifyPropertyChanged,
    public Windows::UI::Xaml::Input::ICommand
{
public:
    DelegateCommand(ExecuteDelegate^ execute, CanExecuteDelegate^ canExecute);
    .
    .
    .
private:
    ExecuteDelegate^       m_executeDelegate = nullptr;
    CanExecuteDelegate^    m_canExecuteDelegate = nullptr;
    .
    .
    .
};
```

And a typical instantiation of my `DelegateCommand` class passes a weak pointer and a function pointer into the constructor from a class that has the implementation of the `Execute` and `CanExecute` methods:

```
Commands::Instance->UndoCommand = ref new DelegateCommand(
    ref new ExecuteDelegate(this, &SVGDocumentUserControl::ExecuteUndoCommand),
    ref new CanExecuteDelegate(this, &SVGDocumentUserControl::CanExecuteUndoCommand));
```

I'm sure this is a simple question, but it is unclear to me from what I have read, so exactly how would one define the two C++/CX delegates in C++/WinRT?

```
public delegate void ExecuteDelegate(Platform::Object^ parameter);
public delegate bool CanExecuteDelegate(Platform::Object^ parameter);
```

[Edit: I am also scratching my head on how to define the constructor's function pointers in the *.idl file.]

Thank you for your patience.

Comment: Just a thought, when you feed your existing code to the C++/CX compiler, can't it export the metadata (I guess that would be `winmd` format) in a way that lets you see the correct raw declarations?

Comment: @BenVoigt: I ran winmdidl.exe on my CX app's *.winmd file. The bits that I needed, specifically the delegate definitions, weren't in there. Good thought though.

Comment: As I understand, your C++/CX code does indeed generate a .winmd file. If so, you can instead run C++/WinRT's cppwinrt.exe against that .winmd, and have it generate the respective header files. That should give you the full declaration, including the delegates.

Comment: There's also [Move to C++/WinRT from C++/CX](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/move-to-winrt-from-cx) with a section on delegates, so maybe that is of help as well.

Comment: @IInspectable I read that section on delegates. I hope I'm mistaken, but it didn't seem to cover how I am trying to use them. I just tried cppwinrt.exe on the *.winmd file. I get the error: "Type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.FlowDirection' could not be found." Is there an include/library directory I should add to the developer console command line? Thanks.

Comment: Have you passed the `-reference` command line option? I believe you can pass either `-reference local` or `-reference sdk` to get access to the system-provided .winmd files.

Comment: @IInspectable Unfortunately, I get the error regardless of what value is assigned to `-reference`. :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see that your code has the delegates as public types (not internal). So, assuming that you really do need them to be part of the public API of your component, you simply define your delegates in MIDL3 (along with a test class with a constructor accepting them like this:

```cs
namespace BlankApp1
{
    delegate void ExecuteDelegate(Object param);
    delegate Boolean CanExecuteDelegate(Object param);

    [default_interface]
    runtimeclass TestClass
    {
        TestClass(ExecuteDelegate execute, CanExecuteDelegate canExecute);
    }
}
```

From there, you have projected types for these delegates, along with all the rich support provided by C++/WinRT for delegates. For instance, the implementation of `TestClass` is simple:

```cpp
struct TestClass : TestClassT<TestClass>
{
    TestClass() = default;
    TestClass(BlankApp1::ExecuteDelegate const& execute, BlankApp1::CanExecuteDelegate const& canExecute)
        : m_execute(execute)
        , m_canExecute(canExecute)
    {}

private:
    ExecuteDelegate m_execute;
    CanExecuteDelegate m_canExecute;
};
```

And instantiating that type, using C++/WinRT's rich delegate support is easy, and will give you the same lifetime safety semantics that you had in C++/CX (i.e., storing a weak ref to the object along with its member function pointer).

```cpp
struct MyClass : winrt::implements<MyClass, winrt::Windows::Foundation::IInspectable>
{
    MyClass() = default;

    void Execute(winrt::Windows::Foundation::IInspectable const&)
    {
    }

    bool CanExecute(winrt::Windows::Foundation::IInspectable const&)
    {
        return true;
    }

    TestClass CreateCommand()
    {
        return TestClass{
            ExecuteDelegate{ get_weak(), &MyClass::Execute },
            CanExecuteDelegate{ get_strong(), &MyClass::CanExecute }
        };
    }
};
```

Comment: That did the trick. The proper declaration of the delegates in the *.idl file is what threw me off. And that they aren't visible in the source code I work with directly. Thank you. I am now in business!